# Promise-driven animation

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, animation

Inspired by [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23213332/bash-shell-simulation-in-browser), I've attempted to code such animation, mostly to get some more practice with async, promises and Q.js:

[(Live demo)](http://codepen.io/Kos/pen/ClqeJ?editors=001)

```
function addOutput(s) {
  $('<div>').text(s).appendTo(wnd);
  //return Q.defer().promise;
  return Q.delay(100).then(function() { return addPrompt(); });
}

function addInput(s) {
  var l = $('.prompt:last');
  return addLettersRecursive(l, s);
}

function addPrompt() {
  var prompt = "kos@codepen % ";
  var l = $('<div>').text(prompt).addClass('prompt').appendTo(wnd);
  return Q.delay(900);
}

function addLettersRecursive(container, s) {
  container.append(s.charAt(0)); // dangerous :(
  var row_complete = Q.defer();
  Q.delay(100).then(function() {
    if (s.length <= 1) {
      Q.delay(300).then(function() {
        row_complete.resolve();
      });
    }
    addLettersRecursive(container, s.substr(1)).then(function() {
      row_complete.resolve();
    })
  });
  return row_complete.promise;
}

// Usage

addPrompt(">>> ")
.then(function() { return addInput("whoami"); })
.then(function() { return addOutput("kos"); })
.then(function() { return addInput("uname -a"); })
.then(function() { return addOutput("Javascript in codepen.io, powered by Q.js"); })
.then(function() { return addInput("raz dwa"); })
.then(function() { return addOutput("zsh: command not found: raz"); })
.then(function() { return addInput("trzy cztery"); })
.then(function() { return addOutput("zsh: command not found: trzy"); })
.done();
```

I'm not really satisfied by this implementation, though. How can I simplify it? Here are the specific concerns I have:

1. I implemented `addInput` in terms of a recursive helper function `addLettersRecursive` which still is overly complicated according to my gut feeling.
2. There's this `.then(function() { return function_that_returns_promise(args); });` pattern all over, which seems like a very verbose way of chaining behaviour.

What I have tried:

1. I attempted to unwind the recursion by stacking the promises one on top of another in a loop, which was a bit tricky to implement because of the selective closure involved. There's some improvement but still looks messy:

   ```
   function addInput(s) {
     var container = $('.prompt:last');
     var d = Q.delay(0);
     for (var i=0; i<s.length; ++i) {
       d = d.then(function(i) { return function() { // pass i by value
         container.append(s.charAt(i));
         return Q.delay(100);
       }}(i));
     }
     return d.then(function() { return Q.delay(300); });
   }
   ```
2. I'm not sure if this kind of pattern is typical to promise-driven code, or I'm just doing something sub-optimally. One thing that came to my mind is this substitution:

   ```
     /* before */ .then(function() { return addInput("whoami"); })
     /* after  */ .then(addInput.bind(null, "whoami"))

     /* before */ return d.then(function() { return Q.delay(300); });
     /* after  */ return d.then(Q.delay.bind(Q, 300));
   ```

   Is it a good track?

Generally I haven't seen much "real life" uses of promises yet except the book cases, so if anything else looks out of the ordinary or sub-optimal, please raise it.

Answer (score 2):

This stuff is hard to get right, at this point good promise driven code seems more like an art than engineering.

From a CodeReview perspective, your code is fairly easy to follow, except for one thing which got me stumped for a little while, `row_complete` should really be named `char_complete`, and then suddenly `addLettersRecursive` will make more sense.

There are at least 3 additional ways you can deal with `.then(function() { return function_that_returns_promise(args); });`

1. Change your functions ( like `addInput` ) to return a function, like this:

   ```
   function addInput(s) {
     return function addInputWrapper(){
       var l = $('.prompt:last');
       return addLettersRecursive(l, s);
     }
   }
   ```

   Then you can call simply `.then( addInput( 'whoami' ) )`
2. Create a generic wrapper function like this:

   ```
   function wrap( f ){
     var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);
     return function wrapper(){
       return f.apply( this, args );
     }
   }
   ```

   Then you can call `.then( wrap( addInput, 'whoami' ) )`
3. Generate a `lambdafy` function like this :

   ```
   function lambdafy( f )
   {
     var lambda = function(){
       var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
       return function(){
         f.apply( this , args );
       }
     }
     return lambda;
   }
   ```

   Then you can `addInput = lambdafy( addInput )` and `.then( addInput( 'whoami' ) )`

Comment: Thanks! 1 crossed my mind but probably isn't conventional, for instance `Q.delay()` returns the promise immediately. 2 looks very similar to `Function.bind` in usage, and I think I'll stick with this approach for now.